# I want to merge two .png images

Tags: c#

I want to merge two .png images. but when I ga to save them there occurred an error called a generic error occurred in gdi+. I want to continue my project as soon as possible. please help me. Thanks

```
private void MergeImages(string ImageBack,string ImageFore)
        {
            try
            {
            System.Drawing.Graphics myGraphic = null;
        Image imgB;// =new Image.FromFile(ImageBack);
        imgB = Image.FromFile(ImageBack);
            //FileInfo fileInfoBack = new FileInfo(ImageBack);

        Image imgF;// =new Image.FromFile(ImageBack);
        imgF = Image.FromFile(ImageFore);
        //Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(imgB.Width, imgB.Height,imgB.PixelFormat );
          //  tempBitmap.Save("a"+fileInfoBack.Extension);

        Image m;
        m = Image.FromFile(ImageBack);
      //  m = Image.FromFile("a" + fileInfoBack.Extension);
        myGraphic = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(m);
        myGraphic.DrawImageUnscaled(imgB,0,0);
        myGraphic.DrawImageUnscaled(imgF,posX,posY);
        myGraphic.Save();


        m.Save(ImageBack.Replace(".jpg",".jpeg"),System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        //m.Save(ImageBack, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
      // m.Save("d.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private void btnFileProtector_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtFileProtector.Text=openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void btnFilesToProtect_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        listFilesToProtect.Items.Clear();
        if (openFileDialog2.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (openFileDialog2.FileNames.Length>0)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<openFileDialog2.FileNames.Length;i++)
                {
                    listFilesToProtect.Items.Add(openFileDialog2.FileNames[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnLoad2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        posX = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        posY = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
       // heightBackImage = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
       // widthBackImage = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);

        if (listFilesToProtect.Items.Count>0)
        {
            foreach(object it in listFilesToProtect.Items)
            {
                MergeImages(it.ToString(), txtFileProtector.Text);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what error did you get (exception/error message) ? what exactly do you want to achieve when you say "merging" 2 PNG ?

Comment: Instead of reading a file into the variable `m`, try creating a new `Bitmap` with the desired dimensions and then create a `Graphics` on that Bitmap. Then you can draw both your images onto the new Bitmap and finally save it to disk.

Comment: @Yahila
error message is.. "A generic error occurred in GD+.
I means that, I give one image and want to join another image to the base image. I think u get an idea

Comment: @Ntini.. Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(imgB.Width, imgB.Height); I use this code also. But the final image resoultions are chaged.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us at which line this exception is thrown, So I am going to *guess* here. This error usually occurs when the path of the image that you are trying to load/save is not correct, so check the path for both `ImageBack` and `ImageFore`.
Also make sure that the file you are trying to load/save to is not open by another process including your application.

It is worth to mentioned here that you should dispose the images/graphics when you finish from using them, for instance by use `using`. like

```
using(Image imgB = Image.FromFile(ImageBack))
{ 
    //the code that is using the imgB here
}
```

Comment: Thanx Jalal. Path is not incorrect. because It execute for a .jpeg image and .png image. Even though I cant find the error

Comment: What do you mean by `It execute for a .jpeg image and .png image`? is it throw exception only if the image format is something else?

Comment: my application is run correctly only for the .jpeg and .png format. But for other formats it gives a run time error.."A generic error occured in GDI++

Comment: what is the other formats? because then maybe the `Image` class doesn't really support them..

Comment: if both picture are same format(like both are .jpeg or .png) or one is .gif and other is .png it couldn't excute well..
if (listFilesToProtect.Items.Count>0)
   {
    foreach(object it in listFilesToProtect.Items)
    {
                    MergeImages(it.ToString(), txtFileProtector.Text);
                   
    }
}   i think this code has the error

Comment: I am not sure but _maybe_ the problem is with merging `.gif`. try to merege two different images formats without `.gif` being any of them. Also you can rid from the call `myGraphic.Save();` here.

Comment: System.Drawing.Graphics myGraphic = null;
Image imgB;
imgB = Image.FromFile(ImageBack);
FileInfo fileInfoBack = new FileInfo(ImageBack);
Image imgF;
imgF = Image.FromFile(ImageFore);
Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(imgB.Width, imgB.Height);
tempBitmap.Save("a"+fileInfoBack.Extension);
Image m;
m = Image.FromFile("a" + fileInfoBack.Extension);
myGraphic = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(m);
myGraphic.DrawImageUnscaled(imgB,0,0);
myGraphic.DrawImageUnscaled(imgF,posX,posY);
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
m.Save(textBox5.Text+fileInfoBack.Extension);
m.Dispose();
}

Comment: there is a problem of picture resolution. results back image is different to the original picture. And also result back image has been stretched. wt the reason for it